# Configuring custom http client for AWS Dynamodb connection?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-dynamodb, httpclient

I have dynamoDBAAPI interface as following:

```
type dynamoDBAPI interface {
    PutItem(ctx context.Context, params *dynamodb.PutItemInput, optFns ...func(*dynamodb.Options)) (*dynamodb.PutItemOutput, error)
    GetItem(ctx context.Context, params *dynamodb.GetItemInput, optFns ...func(*dynamodb.Options)) (*dynamodb.GetItemOutput, error)
    Scan(ctx context.Context, params *dynamodb.ScanInput, optFns ...func(*dynamodb.Options)) (*dynamodb.ScanOutput, error)
}
```

While creating a connection I am checking if it exist in dynamoDBAPI interface otherwise create a new dynamoApi from config as following:

```
    if dynamoDBAPI == nil {
        cfg, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(context.Background())
        if err != nil {
            panic(fmt.Sprintf("failed to configure dynamodb, %v", err))
        }
        dynamoDBAPI = dynamodb.NewFromConfig(cfg)
    }

    return dynamoDBAPI
```

I need to create configure custom http client as following:

```
    if dynamoApi == nil {
        httpClient := awshttp.NewBuildableClient().WithDialerOptions(func(d *net.Dialer) {
            d.KeepAlive = 300
        })
        cfg, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(context.Background(), config.WithHTTPClient(httpClient))
        if err != nil {
            panic(fmt.Sprintf("failed to configure dynamodb, %v", err))
        }
        dynamoApi = dynamodb.NewFromConfig(cfg)
    }

    return dynamoApi
```

Is it possible I can pass the same custom http client in interface as part of dynamodb.Options or in any other way? If yes how I can achieve it. Thank you in advance.